# Query django default user model object using email

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django's custom user model. I want to query a user object based on email attribute. I am doing like:

```
user  = User.objects.get(email = email)
```

but it gives me error

> File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 399, in get
>       self.model._meta.object_name
>       main.models.Code.DoesNotExist: Code matching query does not exist.

Comment: That means that there is no `User` object with that `email`, this is not an error with the query itself, but there is simply no such user, as the `DoesNotExist` hints.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem *Code matching query does not exist.* I think it means he is querying a model named `Code` and problem is not with `User` model. Am I right?

Comment: I think there is a model named `Code` in your application and you are querying that model. The instance of that model `DoesNotExist` according to your query parameters. If yes, can you update your question with that piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

The `User.objects.get` function will throw an error if nothing matches the query. You can either use a `try/except` block to handle this error, or do something like:

```
user = None
users = User.objects.filter(email=email)
if users.exists():
    user = user.first()
```